# How does Unity3D set its icon on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine

When I start a Unity3D program on Linux (not via desktop launcher), the program has an icon. As far as I was told, a program entry would only get an icon, when launched via desktop launcher.
Seems like Unity3D found a way to do it differently. Does anyone know how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like they are setting the *X11* property [`_NET_WM_ICON`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html) directly. 
They do set a very low icon size, though, which is not optimal.